# Hacer una condición para poner un número (o no) en un array

Tags: java, array, if, bucles

estoy aprendiendo como primer lenguaje Java y voy por Arrays, he de decir que nunca he programado y buscando información por internet no he encontrado nada que me ayude a resolver este problema:
"Haz un programa para llenar un vector de 10 elementos de valor entero. Estos enteros tienen que estar comprendidos entre 0 y 20".

Este es el código que llevo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] ArrayNums = new int[10];
    int i;
    System.out.println("Introduce 10 numeros.");
    Scanner sca = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println("Introduce el siguiente numero: ");
        ArrayNums[i] = sca.nextInt();
        if (ArrayNums[i]<=0 || ArrayNums[i]>20) {
            System.out.println("El numero tiene que ser mas grande que 0 y mas pequeño que 20.");
        }
    }
    sca.close();
}
```

No consigo hacer que solo se me guarden dentro del Array los que cumplen la condición de ser mayores que 0 y menores que 20. Lo único es que si una de estas dos condiciones se cumplen, el número se me guarda igualmente, pero habiendo saltado el aviso de "no cumple la condición".

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que gestionar la otra parte de la condición mediante la sentencia `else` y con la ayuda de una variable intermedia.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] ArrayNums = new int[10];
    int i;
    int numero;
    System.out.println("Introduce 10 numeros.");
    Scanner sca = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println("Introduce el siguiente numero: ");
        numero = sca.nextInt();
        if (numero<=0 || numero>20) {
            System.out.println("El numero tiene que ser mas grande que 0 y mas pequeño que 20.");
        }else{
            ArrayNums[i] = numero;
        }
    }
    sca.close();
}
```

Es decir, tu lo que estas haciendo en tu código es agregarlo directamente al Array y después comprobar sobre dicho Array. Es decir, el valor lo has agregado igualmente antes de realizar la condición, por lo que a pesar de que muestres el mensaje por pantalla después de la condición, no estás eliminado ese valor que ya está agregado al array.

Por eso creo que lo más práctico es crearte una variable intermedia y realizar la condición con ella. En caso de que sea errónea, muestras el mensaje, y en caso de ser correcta, agregas el valor al array.